# Material UI Trim Text Search

Tags: material-ui

I would like to trim the text entered in the autocomplete UI to make the search successful.
In case I search for the text "fath " it should display the results for key word searched "fath".

https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `value` and `onChange` props to achieve this - take a look at the [Controlled States section](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states)  in the documentation that you linked.

You can model your `onChange` method to trim the input when user input is received (this could cause problems if spaces can occur between words) or you can trim the input value right before using it in an API call or whatever. [Javascript Trim method for strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) can easily trim the value for you.

```js
// Sample onChange handler
// Beware - this might block spaces from between words
onInputChange = (ev) => {
    this.setState({ inputValue : ev.target.value.trim() })
}

// Better way might be to trim right before using
callToSearch = () => {
    const { inputValue} = this.state;
    console.log(inputValue.trim());
}
```

Comment: this accepted answer seems to be for an old version of MUI, for MUI v5 see the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/76690981/498463

Answer (score 1):

If your options have multiple words or if you don't want to do the trim manually, you can use the `customFilter` prop along with `createFilterOptions` and set `trim` to `true`.

```
<Autocomplete filterOptions={createFilterOptions({ trim: true })} />
```

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#custom-filter